# Python script to reformat a CSV file outputting an empty file

Tags: python, csv

Can anyone help me out with my python script that converts an input csv to an output csv with the correct formatting currently it's only outputting an empty csv file. The format parameters are as follows:

Input:

1. Each row in the input csv contains one of the 7 columns in the output csv rows
2. There are empty rows containing just quotes to be aware of
3. There are multiple number of rows in the input file for each data set some will have extra rows some will have missing rows

Output:

1. Each row in the output csv should have 7 columns
2. From the input csv any rows that include empty data such as two quotes should be removed in the output csv
3. From the input csv use 'Investor focuses:' as an anchor point to determine the last column in the row data set
4. From the input csv any row's data sets that doesn't include an '@' symbol insert '"Email:NA",' into the 4th column of that row
5. From the input csv any row's data sets that doesn't include an 'Phone:' insert '"Phone:NA",' into the 5th column of that rowA"
6. From the input csv remove any rows that just include just "Email:" or "Placeholder image"
7. The content of the csv file should have a the content of each cell in one set of quotations and a comma at the end outside the quotations for the correct csv formatting
8. The input file will always be input.csv and the output will always be output.csv

This is an example of the input data format:

```
"",
"Username 001",
"",
"Partner",
"London, United Kingdom",
"Emails:",
"",
"user@example.eu",
"Phone:00-000-000-000",
"Investor types: Private Equity Firm, Venture Capital",
"Investment focuses: Financial Services, Artificial Intelligence, Machine Learning, Software, Advice, Professional Services, Semiconductor, Agriculture, AgTech, Biotechnology, Medical, Medical Device, Veterinary, CRM, Information Technology, E-Commerce, Internet, Robotics, Security, Public Safety, Service Industry Show past investments",
"Placeholder image",
"",
"Username 002",
"",
"Co-Founder and General Partner",
"London, United Kingdom",
"Emails:",
"",
"Phone:00-00-0000-0000",
"Investor type: Micro VC",
"Investment focuses: Semiconductor, Software, SaaS, Health Care, CleanTech, Data Visualization, Hardware, Internet of Things, Smart Cities, Financial Services, FinTech, CMS, IaaS, Information Technology, Internet, PaaS, Web Design, Web Development, Web Hosting, Machine Learning, Robotics, Artificial Intelligence, Computer, Software Engineering Show past investments",
"",
"Username 003",
"",
"Chief Executive",
"Cardiff, United Kingdom",
"Emails:",
"",
"user@example.wales",
"Investor types: Government Office, Micro VC",
"Investment focuses: Cosmetics, Men's, Sensor, Building Material, Financial Services, FinTech, Marketing, Manufacturing, Artificial Intelligence, Biotechnology, Health Care, Life Science, Software, Blockchain, Enterprise Applications, Industrial Automation, Industrial Manufacturing, Internet, SaaS, Supply Chain Management, Information Technology, Wellness Show past investments",
"",
"Username 004",
"",
"Partner",
"London, United Kingdom",
"Emails:",
"",
"user@example.com",
"Phone:00-00-0000-0000",
"Investor type: Private Equity Firm",
"Investment focuses: Construction, Aerospace, Financial Services, Hospital, Pharmaceutical, Industrial, Machinery Manufacturing, Coffee, Food and Beverage Show past investments",
```

This is how the example data should be outputted:

```
"Username 001","Partner","London, United Kingdom","user001@example.eu","Phone:00-000-000-000","Investor types: Private Equity Firm, Venture Capital","Investment focuses: Financial Services, Artificial Intelligence, Machine Learning, Software, Advice, Professional Services, Semiconductor, Agriculture, AgTech, Biotechnology, Medical, Medical Device, Veterinary, CRM, Information Technology, E-Commerce, Internet, Robotics, Security, Public Safety, Service Industry Show past investments"
"Username 002","Co-Founder and General Partner","London, United Kingdom","Email:NA","Phone:00-00-0000-0000","Investor type: Micro VC","Investment focuses: Semiconductor, Software, SaaS, Health Care, CleanTech, Data Visualization, Hardware, Internet of Things, Smart Cities, Financial Services, FinTech, CMS, IaaS, Information Technology, Internet, PaaS, Web Design, Web Development, Web Hosting, Machine Learning, Robotics, Artificial Intelligence, Computer, Software Engineering Show past investments",
"Username 003","Chief Executive","Cardiff, United Kingdom","user003@example.wales","Phone:NA","Investor types: Government Office, Micro VC","Investment focuses: Cosmetics, Men's, Sensor, Building Material, Financial Services, FinTech, Marketing, Manufacturing, Artificial Intelligence, Biotechnology, Health Care, Life Science, Software, Blockchain, Enterprise Applications, Industrial Automation, Industrial Manufacturing, Internet, SaaS, Supply Chain Management, Information Technology, Wellness Show past investments",
"Username 004","Partner","London, United Kingdom","user004@example.com","Phone:00-00-0000-0000","Investor type: Private Equity Firm","Investment focuses: Construction, Aerospace, Financial Services, Hospital, Pharmaceutical, Industrial, Machinery Manufacturing, Coffee, Food and Beverage Show past investments",
```

Current script:

```
import csv

# Open the input file and create a reader object
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    reader = csv.reader(f_input)

    # Open the output file and create a writer object
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        writer = csv.writer(f_output)

        # Initialize variables to hold data for the current row
        current_name = ""
        current_title = ""
        current_location = ""
        current_email = ""
        current_phone = ""
        current_investor_types = ""
        current_investment_focuses = ""

        # Loop through each row in the input file
        for row_number, row in enumerate(reader):

            # Skip any rows that contain only empty data
            if not any(row):
                continue

            # Check that each row has the correct number of columns
            if len(row) != 1 and len(row) != 3 and len(row) != 4 and len(row) != 7:
                print(f"Error: Row {row_number} has {len(row)} columns. Skipping row.")
                continue

            # Extract the data from the row and store it in the appropriate variables
            if row[0] != "":
                current_name = row[0]
            elif row[2] != "":
                current_title = row[2]
            elif row[3] != "":
                current_location = row[3]
            elif "@" in row[4]:
                current_email = row[4]
            elif "Phone:" in row[4]:
                current_phone = row[4]
            elif row[5] == "Investor types:":
                current_investor_types = row[6]
            elif row[5] == "Investment focuses:":
                current_investment_focuses = row[6]

                # Check if the current row contains all necessary data
                if current_name != "" and current_title != "" and current_location != "":
                    # If the current row does not contain an email, add "Email:NA" to the appropriate column
                    if current_email == "":
                        current_email = "Email:NA"

                    # If the current row does not contain a phone number, add "Phone:NA" to the appropriate column
                    if current_phone == "":
                        current_phone = "Phone:NA"

                    # Remove any rows that just include "Email:" or "Placeholder image"
                    if current_email == "Email:" or current_email == "Placeholder image":
                        current_email = ""

                    # Write the data for the current row to the output file
                    writer.writerow([current_name, current_title, current_location, current_email, current_phone, current_investor_types, current_investment_focuses])

                    # Reset the variables for the next row
                    current_name = ""
                    current_title = ""
                    current_location = ""
                    current_email = ""
                    current_phone = ""
                    current_investor_types = ""
                    current_investment_focuses = ""

        # Check if the last row in the input file contains all necessary data
        if current_name != "" and current_title != "" and current_location != "":
            # If the last row does not contain an email, add "Email:NA" to the appropriate column
            if current_email == "":
                current_email = "Email:NA"

            # If the last row does not contain a phone number, add "Phone:NA" to the appropriate column
            if current_phone == "":
                current_phone = "Phone:NA"

            # Remove any rows that just include "Email:" or "Placeholder image"
            if current_email == "Email:" or current_email:
                current_email = ""

            # Write the data for the last row to the output file
            writer.writerow([current_name, current_title, current_location, current_email, current_phone, current_investor_types, current_investment_focuses])
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program? Or you can put a `print` every now and then to see what it does.

Comment: The input file is not a csv format.

Comment: @Friedrich Yeah it prints out the data but won't go into the csv output for some reason

Comment: @EmanuelP I've updated the Input data to match the correct csv format and it hasn't changed the output results

Comment: The input doesn't have columns like a normal csv file. Instead, each field is on a separate row. So code like `elif row[5] == "Investment focuses:"` will not work with this input. There is no 5th column. There is only one column per row in the input.

Comment: I would take your rulebook and manually go over each line in the first few records, then write pseudocode. This will help you either identify errors in your rulebook or slowly create a skeleton for your program.

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv

# Open the input file and create a reader object
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    reader = csv.reader(f_input)

    # Open the output file and create a writer object
    with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
        writer = csv.writer(f_output)

        # Initialize variables to hold data for the current row
        current_name = ""
        current_title = ""
        current_location = ""
        current_email = "Email:NA"
        current_phone = "Phone:NA"
        current_investor_types = ""
        current_investment_focuses = ""

        # Loop through each row in the input file
        for row_number, row in enumerate(reader):
            row_content = row[0].strip()

            # Skip any rows that contain only empty data
            if not row_content:
                continue

            # Extract the data from the row and store it in the appropriate variables
            if "Email:" in row_content and "@" in row_content:
                current_email = row_content
            elif "Phone:" in row_content:
                current_phone = row_content
            elif "Investor types:" in row_content:
                current_investor_types = row_content
            elif "Investment focuses:" in row_content:
                current_investment_focuses = row_content

                # Write the data for the current row to the output file
                writer.writerow([current_name, current_title, current_location, current_email, current_phone, current_investor_types, current_investment_focuses])

                # Reset the variables for the next row
                current_email = "Email:NA"
                current_phone = "Phone:NA"
                current_investor_types = ""
                current_investment_focuses = ""
            elif row_content not in ["Email:", "Placeholder image"]:
                if current_title == "":
                    current_title = row_content
                elif current_location == "":
                    current_location = row_content
                else:
                    current_name = row_content
                    current_title = ""
                    current_location = ""
```